Problem uploading image from express to s3
I want to upload an image to s3 but cant, eventhough a similar api like that can work normally.

exports.createPost = async (req, res) => {
    const {  user_id, title, caption } = req.body;// Assuming the upload middleware saves the file path in req.file.path

    let thumbnail_url = null;

    thumbnail_url = req.file.location;

    try {
        const user = await User.findByPk(user_id);
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User does not exist' });
        }
        const newPost = await Post.create({
            user_id,
            title,
            caption,
            thumbnail_url
        });

        res.status(201).json({ post_id: newPost.post_id });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error creating post:", error);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error creating post' });
    }
};


exports.createPostBlock = async (req, res) => {
    const { post_id, type, order } = req.body;

    try {
        // Ensure required fields are present
        if (!post_id || !order) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'post_id and order are required fields' });
        }

        let content = null;

        // If type is 'image', handle the file upload
        if (type === 'image' && req.file) {
            content = req.file.location; // The file URL returned from S3 or local storage
        } else if (type === 'text') {
            content = req.body.content; // Assuming content is passed for text posts
        }

        // Create PostBlock in the database
        const postBlock = await Post_block.create({
            post_id,
            type,
            content,
            order,
        });

        res.status(201).json({ message: 'Post block created successfully', postBlock });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating post block:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error creating post block', details: error.message });
    }
};

Here is the controller code, in this code, the createPostBlock works fine, uploading the image to s3 and write the url into the database. But somehow the createPost can not do the same.
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const postController = require('../controllers/post.controller');
const upload = require('../utils/middleware/image_upload');
const auth = require('../utils/middleware/auth');

// Route to create a post
router.post('/create-post', postController.createPost, upload.single('thumbnail_url'));
router.post('/create-post-block', postController.createPostBlock,upload.single('content'))
// router.post('/postCreate', postController.createPost);
router.post('/like', postController.likePost);
router.post('/unlike', postController.unlikePost);
router.post('/removeVote', postController.removePostReaction)
// Route to get a post with blocks
router.get('/:post_id', postController.getPostById);
router.get('/allPosts/:user_id', postController.getAllPosts);
module.exports = router;

this is the api route, it keep returning this error when i try to create a post with thumbnail_url, removing it and the api works fine.
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (/home/chinatsu/Programming/EduConnect/educonnect-backend/node_modules/multer/index.js:40:19)
    at Multipart.<anonymous> (/home/chinatsu/Programming/EduConnect/educonnect-backend/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:107:7)
    at Multipart.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at Multipart.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at HeaderParser.cb (/home/chinatsu/Programming/EduConnect/educonnect-backend/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:358:14)
    at HeaderParser.push (/home/chinatsu/Programming/EduConnect/educonnect-backend/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:162:20)
    at SBMH.ssCb [as _cb] (/home/chinatsu/Programming/EduConnect/educonnect-backend/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:394:37)
    at feed (/home/chinatsu/Programming/EduConnect/educonnect-backend/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:248:10)
    at SBMH.push (/home/chinatsu/Programming/EduConnect/educonnect-backend/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:104:16)

can someone please tell me why the createPost does not work
I tried putting the upload.single before the controller like other people on stackoverflow but it does not work.
